# Cloudpage to Salesforce Lead

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

I'm trying to trigger emails based on a form submission. The issue is I need to create the lead in Salesforce based on the form submission and before the email send in marketing cloud. I'm using Cloudpages and plan on using the submissions as an entry to a journey that creates the sign ups as leads. From there, I need to send those responses to the proper channel depending on what they submitted on the form. I was thinking of separate journeys, but is there a more efficient way using automation studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will advise you to have the form create the lead is Sales Cloud, and then use Salesforce data entry event in Journey Builder, where you will be monitoring the Lead object, for new records being created. Once your form creates a lead, this person will be injected into the journey in real time. You will be able to create decision splits based on data from the lead record, if you want your journey to branch out based on the characteristics of where the lead was created.